# Rails using external API and user feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Using Easy Post, I want to verify if a user's address entered is accurate and real, then provide feedback on validity.

My fear is that we'll have an API hangup, so the user will have to wait for feedback upon submission, instead of it being snappy.

I can handle this with ActiveJob, but then the user has the potential to enter bad address data, and we'll have to notify the customer to return and fix their error.

Of course, we want to keep our customers engaged, but we also want to ensure their submission process is snappy.

What's a proper way to achieve this (best practice)? Delayed job, or just let them wait with a timeout to make sure they don't hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Platanus we developed the [job notifier gem](https://github.com/platanus/job_notifier). It works with ActiveJob and allows you to return asynchronous feedback. With this gem, you can let a user enter the address, and later notify about error or success. I think it is not serious to correct the error later if is not a serious problem and if you have the tool that facilitates you

Comment: That the exact approach I suggested. Never knew that there is a gem for that. Readme.rb looking promisingly. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you may verify entered data is correct in the background.

For example you may get address data by javascript event (onblur) and send it to the EasyPost endpoint by ActiveJob, and let user to fill the rest of your form.

While user fills another form fields, you'll get response from EasyPost and may highlight the fields with green (when it's valid) or red (when it's not).

Also you could render appropriate error message.

That approach will allow you to minimize wring submissions and keep users engaged.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have a specific response to your use case. But here's the approach I'd follow.

If the API is critical to my application, I'd redirect the user to a page where they would be informed that their address was being validated. This would help both my web server and my UX. As I've used Heroku for a while and I know requests that take longer than 30s or so gets terminated.

I'd also look at the API to see a way of adding AJAX validation.

However, as you said you'd also consider ActiveJob, you could have a flag(mostly a db column) on the model to check if the address is valid and while the user transitions around your application, keep him/her informed(probably with a static banner or somewhere consistent with your UI) that his address validation failed.

I believe this way, your users would have had a good experience, while exploring the benefits of your application.